# Resource Id for Text View error while attaching image

Tags: java, android, eclipse

in my spinner i am trying to attach an image and a text View,

Following is my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/UICurrencyCurrencyFlag"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_btn" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/UICurrencyCurrencyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/UICurrencyCurrencyFlag"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the constructor i am using for my Custom Array Adapter

```
public class CustomArrayAdapterForCurrencies extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
{

    private final Activity context;
    public final CharSequence[] keys;

    public CustomArrayAdapterForCurrencies(Activity context, CharSequence[] keys) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.ui_currency_layout,keys);
        this.context = context;
        this.keys = keys;
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = null;
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.ui_currency_layout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
```

When my activity starts, spinner does show image and text but when i try to select spinner it gives error that `Adapter need resouce id for the text view`

How can i resolve this issue,
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `super` statement to

`super(context,  R.layout.ui_currency_layout, R.id.YourTextId , keys);`

Answer (score 1):

You should add this(row layout) in `getView(...)` in your `CustomArrayAdapterForCurrencies`

see this tuts.... http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html